# How to extract cell from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I make a `pandas` dataframe (I am not good at `pandas`, and this may not be very efficient):

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = ['a', 'b']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=colnames)
df_row = ['val1', 'val2']
app = pd.Series(df_row, index=cols)
data = data.append(app, ignore_index=True)
```

I want to access `val1` as a string, not as a `pandas` object.

If I do:

```
cell = data.iloc[[0],[0]]
type(cell)
```

I see that `cell` is of type `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

If I then do:

```
type(cell[`a'])
```

I see that it is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

How can I get `val1` as a `str` object and not a `pandas` object?

Comment: This is off topic but the last 3 lines in your code which add the row to `data` can be replaced by simply doing `data.loc[0] = 'val1', 'val2'`

Comment: @JoeCondron, This doesn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: ...I updated my version of `pandas` and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue for your case is that you are passing lists to `iloc`, you need to pass normal integers `0,0` to `iloc` to get the result you want -

```
In [85]: data.iloc[0,0]
Out[85]: 'val1'
```

Answer (score 4):

For integer based indexing a specific cell in a DataFrame (or Series), [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting) is generally the most efficient:

```
>>> data.iat[0, 0]
'val1'
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the value within the DataFrame as a string:

```
cell = str(data.iloc[0,0])
```